# Change of variable with measures other than the Lebesgue measure.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I ask my question with a specific example in mind.
Consider the integral

\begin{align}
I_k=\int_{\mathbb R}(2\cos(x))^k~d\mu(x),&&k\in\mathbb N\tag{1}
\end{align}

where $\mu=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{x_i}$ is a normalized finite sum of Dirac point masses at some points $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb R$.
Suppose I want to find a measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb R$ such that for every $k$,

\begin{align*}
I_k=\int_{\mathbb R}y^k~d\nu(y).
\end{align*}

Is there a standard way of doing such a change of variable (or maybe more appropriately, "change of measure")?

If $\mu$ in the integral $(1)$ was the Lebesgue measure,
one could simply pose

\begin{align*}
y=2\cos(x)\text{, that is, }x&=\arccos(\tfrac y2)\\
dx&=\frac{-dy}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

and thus obtain
\begin{align*}
I_k=\int_{\mathbb R}(2\cos(x))^k~dx=\int_{\mathbb R}y^k\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\right)~dy=\int_{\mathbb R}y^k~d\nu(y),
\end{align*}
where $\nu$ would be defined as $\mu(A)=\int_{A}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}~dy$ for every $A\subset\mathbb R$ measurable.
However,
the fact that $\mu$ in $(1)$ is neither the Lebesgue measure nor absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure makes me wonder how to do an analog of $(2)$ in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\nu=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{2\cos x_i}\implies\int_\mathbb Ry^k\mathrm d\nu(y)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(2\cos x_i)^k=I_k$$

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this! How embarrassing.

Comment: @JonathanY. Like this, you mean? Funny, when I reread my solution after having posted it, exactly the same thought struck me...

Comment: @JonathanY. Ah, ok. Well, the hat is not very deep, so to speak...